# Best way to order RDD Elements Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

I need to find the most efficient way to **sort globally an RDD of large dimensions**, shuffling as less as possible. I need it for to not incur in performance problems, like for example `outOfMemory` exceptions and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Amount of data you have to shuffle to get sorted RDD is fixed so in a sense every solution that is minimal already shuffles as little as possible. The only that can be improved pushing down sorting mechanism into shuffle but this part is already handled by `RDD.sortBy`, `OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey` or `JavaPairRDD.sortByKey`.

So choose a method that is applicable to your data. So for example:

```
val rdd = org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs.normalRDD(sc, 100, 10, 323L)
rdd.sortBy(identity).take(3)
// Array[Double] = 
//   Array(-2.678684754806642, -1.4394327869537575, -1.2573154896913827)
```

Answer (score 2):

The out of memory exceptions you see are because you have too few partitions and (most probably) your data is skewed so that the ordering makes some partitions really big. 
In any event all the optimization efforts in spark goes toward datasets (and dataframes) so to get better optimization transform the RDDs to to DataFrames and do the ordering using the constructs there